# Java HashMap ArrayList manipulation

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, text-files

I'm really stuck on this one. I already have this code and output.
But what I want is to enhance and make it more complex.
Is this logic is possible?

```
String check = checkpoint1;

boolean passcheckpoint1= false;
int keyIndex = 0;

Map<String,ArrayList> hashMap = new HashMap();

List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>();

ArrayList<String> nextValue = new ArrayList();

while(it.hasNext()){
    line = it.nextLine();

    if (line.contains(check)) {
        passcheckpoint1 = true;
    }
    else if (passcheckpoint1) {
        ArrayList<String> value = new ArrayList();
        value.add(line);
        hashMap.put(keys.get(keyIndex++), value);
    }
    else {
        keys.add(line);
    }
}
```

**this is the previous data of my text file.**

```
1
2
3
4
checkpoint1
a
b
c
d
```

**Output :**

> {1 = [a], 2=[b], 3=[c], 4=[d]}

**and now this is my present data of my text file.**

```
1
2
3
4
checkpoint1
a
b
c
d
checkpoint2
5
6
7
8
checkpoint3
e
f
g
h
```

**Expected Output :**

> {1 = [a], 2=[b], 3=[c], 4=[d] , 5=[e,f,g,h], 6=[e,f,g,h], 7=[e,f,g,h], 8=[e,f,g,h]}

What I want to do is, to put the 5,6,7,8 in the key of hashmap like the 1,2,3,4. But now the value of it is all the same. I want to put the e,f,g,h in one arraylist(nextValue - ArrayList) and put it on value of 5,6,7,8

Comment: what exactly you trying to do ?

Comment: Never make anything so complex that you yourself get lost !

Comment: If the iterator reads the line that contains checkpoint2 then 5-6-7-8 will be store in key of hashmap. then when iterator reads the line and contains it checkpoint3 then e,f,g,h will be stored in arraylist and become value of 5-6-7-8. I also thinking if I reach the checkpoint2, probably the e,f,g,h should be the one to read first then stored it on arraylist then if reach checkpoint3 then it will going to store 5,6,7,8 then include the value of it which is the arraylist

Comment: I dont think this is a hard logic. Just create a variable that tells you in which state (checkpoint) you are, so you can implement it your way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I didnt test it.

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> hashMap = new HashMap();

int checkpoint = 0;
int i = 0;
List<String> keys1 = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> keys2 = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> keys3 = new ArrayList<String>();

while(it.hasNext()) {
    line = it.nextLine();

    if (line.contains('checkpoint1')) {
        checkpoint = 1;
    } else if (line.contains('checkpoint2')) {
        checkpoint = 2;
    } else if (line.contains('checkpoint3')) {
        checkpoint = 3;
    } else {
        switch (checkpoint) {
            case 0: 
                    keys1.add(line);
                    break;
            case 1: 
                    List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
                    values.add(line);
                    hashMap.put(keys1.get(i++),values);
                    break;
            case 2: 
                    keys2.add(line);
                    break;
            case 3: 
                    keys3.add(line);
                    break;
        }
    }
}

for (String k: keys2){
    hashMap.put(k,keys3);
}
```

Comment: Awesome! This works bro! Thanks heaps! I forgot the switch case looool!